# Spring Integration Message Channel Skipping messges

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following configuration which uses Redis as message store.  I don't have java code for this module, but only this configuration file.  This configuration has the following functionality:  When this module receives a message from input channel, it will check the Redis store, if the message doesn't exist (the expression will be evaluated to TRUE), the message will be sent to the output channel which will be put into Redis; if the message already exists (the expression is evaluated to False), the message will be discarded.

Suppose this module is called RedisModule, so i have a stream:

```
 RedisMdule | log
```

The problem is that: when I sent messages to this module, in the log file, it shows the messages #2, #4, #6 etc, the first message is missing, so are the odd number messages.  Are there anything I have missed in this configuration file ?  Many Thanks.

```
  <int:channel id="input"/>
  <int:channel id="output"/>

  <int:filter input-channel="input"
              output-channel="output"
              discard-channel="nullChannel"
              expression="@metadataStore.get(payload) == null"/>

  <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="output"
                              expression="@metadataStore.put(payload, '')"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From big height it looks like you need [`Idempotent Receiver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver), which does exactly similar logic but in the **atomic** manner. See `MetadataStoreSelector` source code:

```
    return this.metadataStore.putIfAbsent(key, value) == null;
```

So, you can configure an `<idempotent-receiver>` with your `RedisMetadataStore` and use `payload` as a `key-expression` option.

It isn't clear by your post how you get logs, because `<int:outbound-channel-adapter>` is *one-way* component.

Maybe you are there in the Spring XD? Where you use the `output` channel for your own purpose, but that really should be an output of your module.

That's really may the reason why you see only **even** messages, because **odd** are sent to your `<int:outbound-channel-adapter>` and the `DirectChannel`  uses `round-robin` balancing strategy by default.

With the `<idempotent-receiver>` you should have only `<bridge input-channel="input" output-channel="output"/>` in your `RedisMdule`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  This helps a lot